# GDB Debugger in Eclipse does not find FILE

Tags: c, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am debugging this code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Add filepath to a chessposition");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    FILE* pchess_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(!pchess_file){
        perror("Error: File not found");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    CHESS_STATE chess_state;

    loadBoard(&chess_state.board_state, pchess_file);
    printBoard(&chess_state.board_state);
    //valdiate board

}
```

I specified the argument *"board.chess"* and the represented file is dropped in the Debug Folder. However, Eclipse seems to have changed the directory. The code works, when executed as usual.

[Structure of the Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGnop.png)

Comment: Have you included `<stdio.h>` header ?

Comment: Yes, there are no errors, when run correctly (no debug). At least this part of the code ;D

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that when debugging Eclipse run in the directory "Project", not "Project/Debug".

Move all files into the "Odin" folder.